# Dotvvm run-time binding to 'object' type

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvvm, binding, dotvvm

i have this class

```
public class Property{
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public object Value {get;set;} 
}
```

i want to create list of the above class `List<Property>` and dynamically add Mark Up Controls Code only 
, so as their website they have an example [HERE](https://www.dotvvm.com/docs/tutorials/control-development-code-only-controls/2.0) and what i did to that example is adding a public property of type `Property` to the `TextBoxWithLabel` class and changed the `setter` of the above example for binding as follows:

```
    [MarkupOptions(AllowHardCodedValue = false)]
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);
            Property.Value = value;
        }
    }
    public static readonly DotvvmProperty TextProperty
        = DotvvmProperty.Register<string, TextBoxWithLabel>(c => c.Text, "");
```

when i run the app and type something in the input field, the `Value` property of Type `Property` still `null` and here is where i'm stuck
i tried also to debug `setter` and it turns out it does not reach there so there is problem with run-time binding, which is 'as their example' this line of code

```
textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, GetValueBinding(TextProperty));
```

any help will appreciated :)

**EDIT:**

for more clarification,i have page called `MainAppPage`
and Markup Control with code behind called `ContentControl`
simply , `MainAppPage` passes `List<Property>` to `ContentControl` using this in `MainAppPage`
`<controls:ContentControl Instance="{value: ClassObject}"/>` then `ContentControl` start iterating through `List<Property>` and creating `InputField`'s that derive from `HtmlGenericControl`

`InputField`'s rendering like a charm in `ContentControl`
only thing is not working is binding , so again, how to bind `Property.Value` to `InputField.Text` so any changes happens in UI from user reflects on `Property.Value` after the `InputField` gets unfocused like any other MVVM pattern ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DotVVM does not assign to the property usning the setter, is sets the underlying property store in `DotvvmBindableObject` instead. It's very simmilar what WPF does with their `DependencyProperty`, it's needed to represent the data bindings. You can actually completely omit the C# property declaration, declaring the field `TextProperty` and calling the DotvvmProperty.Register is enough to declare a property for dotvvm.

Other "problem" is that the controls do not store any data, everything has to be persisted in the view model. You can only use the control properties to data-bind a view model property. I think we are running here into a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I can only tell why your code does not work, but I have no idea what are actually trying to do...

Anyway, if you just want to "bind" your control to a view model property, have a look at https://www.dotvvm.com/docs/tutorials/control-development-markup-controls-with-code/2.0. You can declare the property like that:

```
[MarkupOptions(AllowHardCodedValue = false)]
public string Text
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DotvvmProperty TextProperty
    = DotvvmProperty.Register<string, TextBoxWithLabel>(c => c.Text, "");
```

Use it in the markup of you control

```
@baseType FullName.Of.YourControl
{{value: _control.Text}}
```

And use the control in your page (or other control)

```
<cc:YourControl Text="{value: _this.Property.Value}" />
```

Comment: for more clearfication
i want to bind my Property.Value to TextProperty at runtime 
i can't simply use "<cc:YourControl Text="{value: _this.Property.Value}" />"
cuz it has to be in runtime
so my question shortly:how can i bind Property.Value to any DotvvmProperty 'value'?

Comment: Why are you iterating in the code-behind class and not use something like `<dot:Repeater DataSource="{value: _control.Instance}"><cc:InputField Text="{value: Text}" /></dot:Repeater>`

Comment: i did that , anyway something i noticed
when i pass viewModel with data , the data is shown in UI
but when i modfie data during runtime and debug the viewModel data does not change
what i can tell is the binding is just in one direction !
from MainAppPage to UI is OK
but from UI to MainAppPage Is Not OK !
could you help ? :)

Comment: I can only tell you, that this should work, if you have property access in the binding.

Comment: Simply , how to use Control code-only in a page with binding to viewmodel or any class property ?

Comment: Im still waiting sir